# ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle running inside jetty

Tags: java, servlets, ubuntu, jetty

I am having an issue running a servlet in jetty on Ubuntu 13.04. The server is installed using `apt-get` and started using `sudo service jetty start`. The app requires the class `org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle` but I get a class not found error. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/AbstractLifeCycle
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
at org.cometd.server.CometdServlet.newBayeuxServer(CometdServlet.java:130)
at org.cometd.server.CometdServlet.init(CometdServlet.java:64)
at org.cometd.annotation.AnnotationCometdServlet.init(AnnotationCometdServlet.java:54)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:424)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:          org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
... 37 more
Caused by:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
at org.cometd.server.CometdServlet.newBayeuxServer(CometdServlet.java:130)
at org.cometd.server.CometdServlet.init(CometdServlet.java:64)
at org.cometd.annotation.AnnotationCometdServlet.init(AnnotationCometdServlet.java:54)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:424)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

So far I have:

1) Examined the command used to start jetty to find the classpath using ps:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Dovc.db_config=/home/ubuntu/ovc/data/ovc-repo/config/sql.properties -Dovc.repo_loc=/home/ubuntu/ovc/data/ovc-repo -cp /opt/jetty/lib/jetty-xml-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-http-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-continuation-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-security-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-webapp-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-deploy-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-jmx-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jsp/com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar:/opt/jetty/resources:/opt/jetty/lib/websocket/websocket-api-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/websocket/websocket-client-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/websocket/websocket-common-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/websocket/websocket-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/websocket/websocket-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-io-9.0.4.v20130625.jar org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration /tmp/start2620351902332669076.properties /opt/jetty/etc/jetty.xml /opt/jetty/etc/jetty-jmx.xml /opt/jetty/etc/jetty-http.xml /opt/jetty/etc/jetty-deploy.xml /opt/jetty/etc/jetty-logging.xml /opt/jetty/etc/jetty-started.xml
```

2) Inspected the jar that should contain the missing class:

```
~$ jar -tf /opt/jetty/lib/jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar | grep AbstractLife
org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/AbstractLifeCycle$AbstractLifeCycleListener.class
org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/AbstractLifeCycle.class
```

Can anyone give a suggestion as to what to check next, I am out of ideas? Thank you.

Comment: To see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914196/problem-with-cometd-and-jetty-6-7

Comment: @sunysen I should also mention that the servlet is deployed with no problems on embedded jetty. The link mentions bundling jetty in the war, do I need to do this even though the same jar is provided in ${JETTY_HOME}/lib?

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge jetty* && sudo apt-get install jetty` is worth a shot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the `jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar` in your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib/`

As you can see from the stacktrace, you are attempting to use a class found in jetty-util, from within a webapp.

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
```

This tells you that the *webapp* needs the class from jetty-util.

Because of webapp classloader isolation, and [various rules within Jetty](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.5.v20130815/jetty-webapp/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.java#L106-L136), the classes for `org.eclipse.jetty.util.*` are not provided by the server, and must be provided by the webapp's own `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, led me to the relevant docs [link](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html#configuring-webapp-classloading) for anyone else who finds this question. Is there any great downside to using the `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.setSystemClasses(String Array)` method rather than packaging the jars?

Comment: Using the systemClasses is actually an upside, as your war is independent of the Jetty version. However, you should use `prependSystemClass`, as you would have to replicate the default Jetty configuration, when using `setSystemClass`. See my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32781255/289064).

Answer (score 3):

I got this when combining wiremock and DynamoDBLocal which both includes different versions of jetty. Excluding these dependencies in each of these and then explicitly having these in the pom with a specific version. However, 
seems org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle is only used in up to version 8.2.0.v20160908 (hence it does not solve it to have a newer version)

See example below:

```
<properties>
    <jetty.version>8.2.0.v20160908</jetty.version>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
        <version>${dynamodb-local.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions> 
        <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following into your `webapps/YOURWAR.xml`, within the `<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">` (the `-` in front of `org.eclipse.jetty.util.` is important):

```
<Call name="prependServerClass">
  <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.util.</Arg>
</Call>
```

You need to prepend it, because the order is important and the last one which is added by default is `org.eclipse.jetty.` as documented on [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html#configuring-webapp-classloading). So calling addServerClass would be a no-op, as `org.eclipse.jetty.util.` is already be excluded by `org.eclipse.jetty.`.

Answer (score 1):

Joakim Erdfelt pointed the cause, in case anyone needs a snip of pom code, put this in pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In deployment environment, just make sure your server classpath has included the Spring jar library (e.g spring-2.5.6.jar).

For Spring3, ContextLoaderListener is moved to spring-web.jar, you can get the library from Maven central repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/