# Unable to start Jetty Servlet

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jetty

I am working on a project to mock AWS S3 locally and have decided to use Jetty as the server. I found a quick tutorial http://jlunaquiroga.blogspot.com/2014/01/restful-web-services-with-jetty-and.html that included this code snippet that mocks a server:

```
public class MockRESTClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/hello");//Set the servlet to run.
    server.setHandler(handler);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello SimpleServlet</h1>");
    }
}
```

After (seemingly) resolving all of the dependencies, I attempt to kick off the server, but am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/Destroyable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Destroyable
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

After removing the three lines that bind the servlet, I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:        org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/Destroyable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.finra.s3.MockRESTClient.main(MockRESTClient.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Destroyable
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 61 more
```

I am a bit confused about the `ClassNotFoundException` for `org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/Destroyable` since none of my code explicitly calls anything contained in `org.eclipse.jetty.util`. When I try to import that package, I get a warning that the import is unused.

I searched through SO to find an answer, but the closest thing I found was [ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle running inside jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054286/classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-jetty-util-component-abstractlifecycle-runni) which seems to indicate that my web application needs a class from jetty-util. This makes sense since the classes that it is not able to find are not referenced directly in my code. Now, what doesn't make sense, is that there is no actual web application, yet. I simply wanted to test that the server could run locally.

Please chime in if you know what the issue is. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently you didn't resolve *all* the dependencies.

Comment: `"Now, what doesn't make sense, is that there is no actual web application, yet."` You bound a servlet, so that's not true. Take out the 3 lines that add the servlet in (starting with `ServletHandler handler `...) and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more clear, but what I meant by `after resolving all dependencies` is that there were no visible errors due to dependencies showing in my compiler. I took your advice and removed the three lines that bind the servlet. While there was no popup from the JVM Launcher saying "A Java Exception has occurred," there were still errors and a long stack trace. Please see edit for the new stack trace. Thanks again

Comment: Got it working. Turns out `jetty-util.jar` and `org.eclipse.jetty.util.jar` are two different jars. Thanks for your help