# ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Decorator

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to build a self contained web server using jetty. Since I found a little difficult to manage manually the required jars, I decided to use Maven.
By following some samples and tutorial I ended with this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.RC0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.RC0</version>
</dependency>
```

It does not work: running the program throws the class not found exception on

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.Decorator
```

I tryed different versions, with other missing class. 
code starting the server is this:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");

Server jettyServer = new Server(8383);
jettyServer.setHandler(context);

ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

// Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
    EntryPoint.class.getCanonicalName());

try {
    jettyServer.start();
    jettyServer.join();
} finally {
    jettyServer.destroy();
}
```

Since it is using Jersey as well, I have the dependency on jersey too, I did not post since the error appear to be in jetty. It shouldnt be this difficult, but it is. Any Idea?

Comment: There are newer versions of jetty available than RC0. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.3.6.v20151106 Not sure if updating to a later version is going to help or not.

Comment: Have you considered using Dropwizard? It has all necessary dependencies (such as jetty, jersey, jackson) bundled together and is really easy to use.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I'm a .NET guy, Today I spent all the day trying stuff. I feel quite bitter and frustated. This kind of stuff in the c# works does not happen.

Comment: like @Goibniu says, `9.3.0.RC0` is an unstable/beta/test release.  Use a more stable release (`9.3.6.v20151106` is the most current version).   Also when you encounter an error/exception you should include the entire stacktrace in your question (it helps with answering questions like this)

Comment: do you have any more dependences defined in your pom file? what java version are you using? I have added **org.glassfish.jersey.containers** dependence in pom file and it works (I am working with java8).

Comment: @djvazquez I managed to have it working by depending on version 2.16 of jersey: which version you depend on?

Comment: I use version 2.22.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle running inside jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054286/classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-jetty-util-component-abstractlifecycle-runni)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Looking on the *jersey-container-jetty-http*, you can notice it is using *jetty-util* in an old version. So, once that you exclude this dependency (like the example bellow), it should work properly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with version 9.3.0.M0.
jersey-container-jetty-http don't help me.
Solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
</dependency>
```